# Why does it show symbol not found in a function overloading program?

Tags: java, function, overloading

So I am doing a Function overloading program and wrote the following code:

```
class calculations{
    public void num_cal(int num, char ch){
        if (ch == 's'){
            System.out.println("square of the number: " + Math.pow(num,2));
        }
        else{
            System.out.println("cube of the number: " + Math.pow(num,3));
        }
    }
    public void num_cal(int a, int b, char ch){
        if (ch == 'p'){
            System.out.println("product of the numbers: " + a*b);
        }
        else{
            System.out.println("sum of the numbers: " + a+b);
        }
    }
    public void num_cal(String str1, String str2){
        if (str1.equals(str2)){
            System.out.println(str1 + " and "+ str2 + " are equal");
        }
        else{
            System.out.println(str1 + " and "+ str2 + " are not equal");
        }
    }
}
```

When I run it, it gives an error:

[image]

> Error: cannot find symbol- variable 's'

What exactly is causing this error and why?
Also how do I fix it?

Comment: That code doesn't rise that error, check again.

Comment: hi is not passed as a String it is passed as a variable that's why the program is unable to find the identifier.

Comment: How do I fix it then, I dont understand

Comment: Where does this message come from? not from the code you posted obviously

Comment: Doh - just noticed that this question was asked a year ago.

Answer (score 0):

As @ashish-mishra already mentioned, BlueJ probably assumes that `hi` is a variable, not a string. Try using `"hi"` instead, that might help. [See Java Strings for more info](https://www.w3schools.com/java/java_strings.asp)